# Import/load a couchdb 2.0 .couch file into couch 2.1

Tags: windows, couchdb, fauxton

Somehow my Windows CouchDB 2.0 server acquired hundreds of Shard databases. I made a backup of the data directory. Then I deleted the data directory and install 2.1. Everything is fine.

HOWEVER, I have several *.couch database files that I would like to import/load into 2.1. I place one in the data directory and remove the name..couch to be name.couch. Restart server. But the new database does not appear in the list of databases.

Is it possible to bring back these databases?

Comment: Install CouchDB 2.0 on some other port/machine. Restore you .couch files there. Finally replicate from that instance to your 2.1 instance?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That should work.